# CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation and CGAffineTransformScale transforms different in ios7 and ios8

Tags: ios8, zooming, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I have an UITableView in viewcontroller, and want to zoom out in the center of viewcontroller. It works fine in ios7 as follow code:

```
CGSize appSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size;
CGAffineTransform affineMatrix = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(appSize.width/2, 20);
affineMatrix = CGAffineTransformScale(affineMatrix, 0.5, 0.5);
self.transform = affineMatrix;
```

after updating to ios8, the code may like this to works fine, but in ios7 did not work:

```
CGAffineTransform affineMatrix = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
affineMatrix = CGAffineTransformConcat(affineMatrix,CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -appSize.height/2+40));
self.transform = affineMatrix;
```

who can explain why? How can I works fine in same code?

Answer (score 0):

See the article http://revealapp.com/blog/constraints-and-transforms.html

It explains the problems on affine transformations bug in iOS7. For simple words, you need to manually convert points to pixels on retina devices on iOS 7 using `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`